# how to type special symbols in eclipse in android or office?

Tags: special-characters

What should I do to get special symbols in eclipse like Sigma, Pi and so on.
when I am typing code for Pi (alt+277) it is not converted into the Pi symbol.

*How should I proceed?*

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
- Type your code, eg `277`
- <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd>
- And you have your ɷ (277), π (3c0), Σ (3a3)

A list of unicode characters [here](http://www.unicodemap.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to AU !

Actually to write the greek letter Pi, you must type:

- `Ctrl-Shift-u` followed by `3c0` for small case Pi ........ π
- `Ctrl-Shift-u` followed by `3a0` for upper case Pi ........ Π

For the code to **all** special symbols and characters, you can use `gucharmap` if you are on an ubuntu platform. It is available from the Ubuntu Software Center by default. 
The desktop name of `gucharmap`is "Character Map". 
Launch it and in the left column start by selecting the top most Unicode Block filter "All" or if you want to be more specific, go down the list and select "Greek and Coptic".
In the right pane, select the symbol of your choice. In doing so you will see a `U+wxyz` code in the lower left bottom of the window. This is your unicode. 
Note that in general gucharmap gives you all codes capitalized (upper case). To work use same code but lower case only, either in your terminal or in any other context. 
You can omit leading zero(s) in the Unicode. I.e. for the upper case letter "B", `Ctrl-Shift-u` followed by either 0042 or 42 yields the same result.

@A.B.. Your answer is stricly correct, but as indicated only for the small case omega symbol, which corresponds to the unicode 277, the code the OP produced.